# How can I generate a view or projection matrix for OpenGL 3.+

Tags: opengl, matrix

I'm transitioning from OpenGL 2 to OpenGL 3.+ and to GLSL 1.5. I'm trying to avoid using the deprecated features.

My question how do we now generate the view or projection matrix. I was using the matrix stack to calculate the projection matrix for me;

```
GLfloat ptr[16]; 
gluPerspective(...);
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ptr); 
//then pass ptr via a uniform to the shader
```

But obviously the matrix stack is deprecated. So this approach is not the best an option going forward.

I have the 'Red Book', 7th ed, which covers 3.0 & 3.1 and it still uses the deprecated matrix functions in it's examples.

I could write some utility-code myself to generate the matrices. But I don't want to re-invent this particular wheel, especially when this functionality is required for every 3D graphics program.

What is the accepted way to generate world,view & projection matrices for OpenGL? Is there an emerging 'standard' library for this? Or is there some other hidden (to me) functionality in OpenGL/GLSL which I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Unofficial OpenGL Software Development Kit](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html).

Not only does it include the GLM library, there's also a GL Util module which contains a replacement for the [matrix stack](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classglutil_1_1_matrix_stack.html).

You can also see [this tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2007.html) for an introduction to the library.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure somebody will write a whole novel on how to calculate the perspective projection and the view matrix, but that's just unnecessary. You'll find this information in any modern book on 3D graphics. If you don't have access to books like [Real-Time Rendering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568814240) then there are [OpenGL](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/index.html) [Tutorials](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html). Alternatively you can just use google. You're looking for common knowledge that's been answered dozens of times. If you don't care about the mathematics then libraries like [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) have functions to generate these matrices.

As for a commonly accepted way of doing this, the principle is always the same for both the view and perspective matrices. There are multiple ways of achieving both (f.e. you can calculate the view matrix as a camera transform and then invert it, or you can calculate it inverted already, the second being much faster), but if you know where to plug your variables then there isn't much difference. The thing you have to look out for is whether you're using the right or left hand coordinate system. Another thing to look out for is DirectX and OpenGL requiring different perspective projection matrices due to the way they define their clip spaces, so make sure that the perspective projection matrix you use is for OpenGL specifically.

Comment: I can generate the matrices by hand, no problem. I just don't want to have to write that code every time. Just wondering what every one else does, maybe its GLM?

Comment: @Ken well GLM is going to calculate the matrix each time aswell. just pack your logic into a function. your projection matrix should be calculated once, unless you change the aspect ratio of the screen, the camera matrix has to be calculated each frame. you should probably just pack both of those into a camera object that'll do things like rotate and move the camera and return the matrices when necessary.

Comment: by 'every time' in my comment above, I mean every time I start a graphics project. My main question is really about what utility or library is commonly for these purposes. Is there a replacement for gluPerspective, glRotate, glOrtho etc? The requirement for this functionality is so pervasive in graphics programming that I would be very surprised if everyone had to go and code their own solution.

Comment: @Ken well it's not really coding your own solution as much as it's writing a basic set of functions. it depends on a lot of things. if you don't want to deal with math then you can use GLM, lots of people do, it'll calculate transformations and do all the math for you. however if you're using a SIMD math library, like the one bullet has then it won't provide you with functions that create a rotation matrix or a perspective projection matrix and thus you'll have to do it yourself

Comment: @Ken your issue is weird one to have, because it's one of code re-usability. just pack your solution into a library and use it when you need it. if you don't want to write your own library then use some one else's like GLM.

Comment: I could write my own linked list for c++, but I choose to use the STL as it was written by smarter people than me AND I have only so many days left on the earth. What's the STL for OpenGL?

Comment: @Ken there is none, GLUT used to be that, but as you know it's for the deprecated OpenGL. There are libraries that provide functionality you may want, like FreeGLUT or GLM, but they're not a widely accepted standard or anything like that.

Comment: It's completely false to say that OpenGL and D3D are different here.  D3D has supported a RH coord system since *at least* version 8, and you can freely use column-major matrices in D3D.  With modern GL you can use LH-coords and row-major matrices if you wish; all that's important is that you pick your convention and keep things consistent.  An interesting side-effect of this is that you can use the D3DX matrix library with a GL program.

Comment: I have to agree with the GLM solution.  It's powerful, easy to use and agrees very, very well with openGL/GLSL.

Comment: @mh01 did you even read the answer? i'm talking about the perspective projection matrix, it's going to be different for OpenGL and DirectX, the clip space z axis for DirectX goes from 0 to 1, not form -1 to 1 like it does with OpenGL, IT'S GOING TO BE DIFFERENT

Comment: @dreta: that's true but it's slightly misleading to call out RH vs LH in the same sentence; a reader who is not aware of things could quite easily assume that the same applies there.  I'd suggest editing your answer to clarify.

Comment: @mh01 you're right, i'll do that

Comment: Reads a lot better now.

Comment: @dreta: clip space is configurable in GL at least, so you can still use the same projection matrix if you want.  The only differences in math between D3D and GL that you can't configure away that I know of are the texture and screen coordinate origins; both are trivially dealt with in shader or resource code, though.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch i've never heard of that, can you cite a source

Comment: @dreta: glDepthRange

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch glDepthRange() has nothing to do with clip space, what it does is set to what coordinates the (-1,1) NDC range is going to be mapped when the image is written to the buffer. Saying that glDepthRange() affects the clip space z range is like saying that glViewport() affects the x and y range, which it doesn't, obviously.

Comment: NDC is homogenous clip space, and that's where the difference between d3d and GL comes in.  You can use the exact same matrices for both d3d and GL, because the only difference between their standard matrices is how their z range maps after division by the w component.  The non-homogenous clip space is defined entirely by your matrices, not the API.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch do you understand how glDepthRange works though?  you started this by saying that the clip space is configurable and you point to the function, which is wrong. and now you're correctly saying that the DX matrix uses half the availible z-range from OpenGL. it's true, but you effectively cut your depth precision by half, which is completely unnecessary. stating such things is unconstructive, that's why i wrote what i did. also NDC is NOT the homogenous clip space, and what is the non-homogenous clip space exactly? i'm sorry but your understanding of this issue is lacking.

Comment: glDepthRange does fix the mapping.  The whole point of it is to allow you to "fix" up differences like this.  You're totally right that I'm mucked up on he terminology, and I should probably double check what I'm doing with my code; I am sharing a single set of matrices for GL and D3D with proper clipping and depth buffer utilization, but maybe there was another step to get the clip space transform working fully.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch it's going to work, just that when using OpenGL your depth buffer is going to get filled in the (0.5, 1) range instead of the (0, 1) range, because your perspective projection matrix mapped your z coordinate to the (0, 1) range like in DirectX, but OpenGL maps that as if z was in the (-1, 1) range. glDepthRange doesn't fix that, it works just like glViewport, it sets to what range the NDC coordinates get mapped, the NDC z range is still going to be (-1, 1) for OpenGL and (0, 1) for DirectX. Really, just read carefuly what the description of glDepthRange says, it's all there.

Comment: @dreta: So I checked the code where I had all this working, and it turns out you're totally right and my memory was just skewed.  I _did_ have glDepthRange(-1,1) to fix that mapping which worked on a particular buggy GL implementation I testing against, but my commit message removing all that pointed out the specific problem there (correct GL implementations of glDepthRange clamp inputs to [0,1]), and my current code just uses two different matrix calculations for D3D vs GL modes.

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for a copy/paste answer, or something a little more code like, here is an implementation for OpenGL. It supports a zoom feature to zoom in/out on the center of the view. I think the variable names are fairly self explanatory.

- Camera is defined by it's position, direction it's looking and its up vector. The view matrix is made up of these values.
- The "lens" you're using (I suppose it could be called?) describes the "cone" that represents what you're looking at in the world. It takes the view angle (how wide narrow the cone of view is) the size of your game window and the near and far cut offs for your view cone. These values make up the projection matrix.

The code below is working and taken from my game. I don't know if this is the most fashionable way to make the matrices, but it works for me and supports the older hardware the I'm targeting.

```
view = createView(getCameraPosition(), getCameraDirection(), getCameraUpVector());
projection = createProjection(cameraViewAngle * zoomFactor, (float) getWindowX() / (float) getWindowY(), nearPlane, farPlane);


Matrix4f createView(Vector3f position, Vector3f direction, Vector3f up) {
    Vector3f.cross(up, direction, getRightVector());
    setRightVector((Vector3f) getRightVector().normalise());

    result.m00 = getRightVector().x;
    result.m10 = getRightVector().y;
    result.m20 = getRightVector().z;
    result.m30 = -(Vector3f.dot(getRightVector(), position));

    result.m01 = up.x;
    result.m11 = up.y;
    result.m21 = up.z;
    result.m31 = -(Vector3f.dot(up, position));

    result.m02 = direction.x;
    result.m12 = direction.y;
    result.m22 = direction.z;
    result.m32 = -(Vector3f.dot(direction, position));

    return result;
}

Matrix4f createProjection(float fov, float aspect, float znear, float zfar) {

    float ymax, xmax;
    ymax = (float) (znear * Math.tan(fov * Math.PI / 360.0));
    xmax = ymax * aspectRatio;
    Matrix4f result = new Matrix4f();
    glhFrustumf2(result, -xmax, xmax, -ymax, ymax, znear, zfar);
    return result;
}

private Matrix4f glhFrustumf2(Matrix4f matrix, float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float znear, float zfar) {
    float twoZNear, deltaW, deltaH, deltaZ;
    twoZNear = 2.0f * znear;
    deltaW = right - left;
    deltaH = top - bottom;
    deltaZ= zfar - znear;
    matrix.m00 = twoZNear / deltaW;
    matrix.m01 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m02 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m03 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m10 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m11 = twoZNear / deltaH;
    matrix.m12 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m13 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m20 = (right + left) / deltaW;
    matrix.m21 = (top + bottom) / deltaH;
    matrix.m22 = (-zfar - znear) / deltaZ;
    matrix.m23 = -1.0f;
    matrix.m30 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m31 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m32 = (-twoZNear * zfar) / deltaZ;
    matrix.m33 = 0.0f;
    return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++, the common answer is to use GLM. For C, you'll have to roll your own matrix math (which really isn't all that much code, a few hundred lines will get you everything you could possibly want). Look at the source code to Mesa or Blender if you want inspiration. Blender in particular has a nice set of matrix math functions. Beware of licensing issues if you intend to copy open source code to reuse though!